# "Open Type" command does not respond in Eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, hotkeys

In Eclipse, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to search for a type.  Unfortunately, Eclipse does not respond to this hotkey in one of my workspaces.

I am running IBM AST 6.1, which is built on Eclipse 3.2.1 (see http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tins_ast_roadmap.html).

When I go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys, it shows the Open Type command is set to the Key Sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> "When" "In Windows".  Is this correct?

I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to search for a resource in this same Workspace, using the same <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys (i.e. the keys are working).  I can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on other workspaces with the same Eclipse installation.

How can I enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>?  What other info do we need to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Do you have the right perspective opened? "Open Type" does work in the Java, JavaEE ... perspectives, but not in the "Synchronize" perspective (for example).

To enable it for the "Synchronize" perspective in eclipse Mars(4.5) first close all your opened editors then go to Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective... and in the "Action Set Availability" tab check the "Java Navigation" action set.

Comment: D'oh!  I had the Resources perspective open.  Thanks!

Comment: In any other perspective, you can go to Window>Customize Perspective...  and from the dialog _Command Groups Availability_ tab check _Java Navigation_ to enable Open Type in that perspective

Comment: Paul Webster answer is right one. In order for shortcut to work in any perspective its Action set must be enabled.

Answer (score 7):

I was already in the right perspective so that was not the cause of my issue. However, closing and re-opening the project fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 7):

Try to delete all Eclipse indexed names in the following way:

1. Go to folder **workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core**
2. Remove all ***.index** files and **savedIndexNames.txt**
3. Restart Eclipse

The recommendations were provided by Mike Schrag and the whole trace can be found [here](http://mschrag.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/open-type-cant-find-your-class.html).

Answer (score 2):

The same problem was resolved for me in a slightly different way... I first checked that I followed the accepted answer, confirmed that the Open Type command was mapped correctly and relevant to the perspective I was in.

But... it was still not functioning, apparently because focus was in a javascript file. Clicking out and assigning focus back to the package explorer tab allowed Open Type to work.

Comment: Same here. When editing a .js file, Ctrl-Shift-T does not work in Eclipse Mars. I wonder if this is a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Although, this is a very old post. But it might be someone get this problem in future.

The above mentioned posts can help in most of the scenarios.
But sometimes, even you select the Java/J2EE perspective, but the selected project is not a nature of java/j2ee. And in that case, the Open Type will open but will not search anything. And to fix that you have to make sure, the selected project has the following code in .project file:

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure that the eclipse window is active in your OS.

Answer (score 0):

For people who need to switch focus from **JavaScripts** every now and then.
1.Go to Window -> Preferences -> General ->Keys .

2.Search for **Open type** from list .

3.***In Description*** : ensure it's **Open a type in a Java editor**

***In Binding*** : **ctrl + shift + T**

***when*** : **In Windows**
4.Apply.

**P.S** : IF any duplicates of **Open Type** please ***unbind*** it or ***restore* defaults.**