# “Open Type” command does not respond in Eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, hotkeys, kde-plasma

As described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870153/open-type-command-does-not-respond-in-eclipse-workspace?answertab=votes#tab-top) I could not open `Open Type` in Eclipse via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

The clue is: When I go to Preferences -> Keys and delete the shortcut, I'm not able to re-add it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Every other combination works, but when I press `T`, the box gets empty.

I use KDE 4.7.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem: In some views some command groups are disabled. (Probably by another plugin)

Solution: Go to `Window` -> `Customize Perspektive` -> `Command Groups Availability` and make shure to enable "Java Navigation".

Answer (score 0):

Check your systems keyboard shortcut. There should be a same shortcut which listen to your shortcut in the first place.

Comment: I only found a shortcut corresponding to ctrl+T (without shift). I deleted this, but with no success.